# Build and interact with checkbox in Scala and Play Framework

Tags: scala, checkbox, playframework

I am new to Scala and the Play Framework.  My goal is to display a checkbox in a view with values from a model.  I would also like to grab those checkbox values from the view, process in a controller (make sure at least one value is selected), and add to a record in a model.

I have my controller built which displays the view and passes the checkbox values:

```
public Result addProfile() {
    List<Service> services = Service.find.all();
    return ok(profile.render(form(ProfileRegister.class), services));
}
```

I have my view built:

```
@(profileForm: Form[Application.ProfileRegister], servicesList: java.util.List[Service])

@main(null) {

            @for(service <- servicesList) {
                <input type='checkbox' name='servicesThis' value=@service>@service <br>
            }
}
```

However, when the view displays, it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have a checkbox appear -- it just displays text with no box to check.  I wanted to also show the value of each record, such as the name property/field.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the value between double or single quotes, i.e. `value="@service"`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this:

```
@for(service <- servicesList) {
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="services" value=@service.name><span>@service.name</span></label>
}
```

What is the best way to grab those checked values (multiple values) in a controller?  And how to display if that record is opened for editing?

I appreciate the help.